# Making data persist in Swift

Tags: swiftui

I'm sorry if this is a naive question, but I need help getting this form to persist in core data. The variables are declared in the data model as strings. I simply cannot get this to cooperate with me. Also, the var wisconsin: String = "" is there because I can't call this view in my NavigationView without it throwing an error.

```
import SwiftUI

struct WisconsinToolOld: View {

    //Variable
    var wisconsin: String = ""
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @State var saveInterval: Int = 5
    var rateOptions = ["<12", ">12"]
    @State var rate = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Spontaneous Respirations after 10 Minutes")) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Respiratory Rate")
                        Spacer()
                        Picker("Rate", selection: $rate, content: {
                            ForEach(rateOptions, id: \.self, content: { rate in
                                Text(rate)
                            })
                        })
                        .pickerStyle(.segmented)
                    }
            Section(header: Text("Result")) {
                HStack {
                    Text("Raw Points")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("\(WisconsinToolInterpretation())")
                }
            }.navigationTitle("Wisconsin Tool")
        }
    }

    func saveTool() {
        do {
            let wisconsin = Wisconsin(context: viewContext)
            wisconsin.rate = rate
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    func WisconsinToolInterpretation() -> Int {
        var points = 0
        if rate == "<12" {
            points += 3
        }
        else {
            points += 1
        }
        return points
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to me your saveTool() does create a new core data object and saves it correctly. But you never actually call it to save. And when you load the view the next time, you don't fetch the core data to display it. Instead you always display the freshly initialised @State vars.

Comment: Ah, I see. I figured that might've been the issue. Is there a better way to call the vars without making them refresh every time?

Comment: Could you please add where you use this view? Is it in a `ForEach`? Or is this a single View?

Comment: I use it as a single view, and then it’s called in a navigation list with a tab bar